# Adjust process privileges by Win32 API on Windows 10

Tags: winapi

I use `CreateFile()` to access a physical drive without being an admin, but only in administrator can that work. I try to use `OpenProcessToken()`, `LookupPrivilegeValue()` and `AdjustTokenPrivileges()` APIs to adjust the permission, but it returns an `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED` error.

I refer to some information and the permission couldn't be modified by Windows 10 later.

Is there any method to avoid administrator when I use `CreateFile()`, or any other solution?

Comment: What is `ERROR_NOT_AL_ASSIGNED` ?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Probably a misspelling of `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED`.

Comment: May be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/18022053/5264491 although that question was tagged c++.

Comment: A user has a fixed set of privileges. Adjusting the token simply lets you turn those privileges on and off. You can't give yourself new privileges that you don't already have. If you need a non-admin user to have access to the device, an admin has to grant that permission to the user.

Answer (score 0):

> AdjustTokenPrivileges() APIs to adjust the permission, but it returns an ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED error.

ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED: The token does not have one or more of the privileges specified in the NewState parameter.

You could refer to the thread:https://stackoverflow.com/a/18022102/11872808

You can't grant yourself privileges that you don't already have.