# Check if given process is running with elevated right with powershell and Get-WmiObject

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have to following part of my script:

`$active_processes = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process | where path -like $path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path | split-path -leaf | Select-Object -Unique)`

It's working fine but I need to check if the process I get after all the script is running with elevated rights to launch another process with elevated rights if neccesary so it can interact with said process. I don't see any information about elevated rights with `Get-WmiObject`, I was wondering if I'm missing it or if there's another way to get that information

I don't need to run the powershell script as administrator. What I need is to find ff any executable requires elevated rights when launched and I need to find this information via powershell.

Answer (score 1):

After some research on how windows knows if it needs admin to run an executable, I concluded that there are a couple ways but the most recommended and reliable is reading the executable manifest, so I wrote the following function:

```
function Get-ManifestFromExe{
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias("Path")]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -IsValid})]
    [String]$FullName
    )
    begin{
        $stringStart = '<assembly'
        $stringEnd = 'assembly>'
    }
    process{
        $content = Get-Content $FullName -Raw
        $indexStart = $content.IndexOf($stringStart)
        $content = $content.Substring($indexStart)
        $indexEnd = ($content.IndexOf($stringEnd)) + $stringEnd.Length
        $content = $content.Substring(0,$indexEnd)
        if($content -match "$stringStart(.|\s)+(?=$stringEnd)$stringEnd"){
            return [XML]$Matches[0]
        } 
    }
}

function Test-IsAdminRequired{
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    [XML]$xml
    )
    $value = $xml.assembly.trustInfo.security.requestedPrivileges.requestedExecutionLevel.level
    if(-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($value)){
        return ($value -eq "requireAdministrator" -or $value -eq "highestAvailable")
    }else{
        Write-Error "Provided xml does not contain requestedExecutionLevel node or level property"
    }
}

$exe = '.\Firefox Installer.exe'
Get-ManifestFromExe -Path $exe
Test-IsAdminRequired -xml $exeManifest
```

It works by extracting the manifest XML from the executable and checking requestedExecutionLevel node's level property, the values accepted for this property are in this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/trustinfo-element-clickonce-application?view=vs-2019#requestedexecutionlevel), and quoted here:

> ***asInvoker***, requesting no additional permissions. This level requires
>   no additional trust prompts.
>
> ***highestAvailable***, requesting the highest permissions available to the
>   parent process.
>
> ***requireAdministrator***, requesting full administrator permissions.

So from this we can conclude that only `highestAvailable` and `requireAdministrator` would need admin privileges, so I check those, with that we will be done **EXCEPT** that some executables I tested (mostly installers) don't require admin to run but instead they prompt the UAC when they ruin their child executable, I don't really see a way to check this.. sorry.

BTW I really enjoyed this question (specially the research), hope this can help you.

---

### SOURCES

1. [What is the difference between "asInvoker" and "highestAvailable" execution levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671579/what-is-the-difference-between-asinvoker-and-highestavailable-execution-leve)
2. [reading an application's manifest file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420852/reading-an-applications-manifest-file)
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/trustinfo-element-clickonce-application?view=vs-2019#requestedexecutionlevel

Comment: I don't need to run the powershell script as administrator. What I need is to find of any executable requires elevated rights when launched and I need to find this information via powershell, sorry if I didn't explain myself

Comment: OK, ill do a little research and come back to you

Answer (score 0):

It's in the  `System.Security.Principal` classes. This returns $true if the current user is elevated to local Administrator:

`(New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)`